# Which players won both FIFA U-20 World Cup and FIFA World Cup?

Tags: football, trivia, world-cup

Which players won both [FIFA U-20 World Cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_U-20_World_Cup) (until 2005 known as the FIFA World Youth Championship) and [FIFA World Cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup)?

This would show players who excelled both in the young age and in their later career.

I guess that there will not be too many such players but, of course, I might be wrong.

I did not find any source where I could systematically search for statistics like this. By some more-or-less random searching I was able to find [Maradona](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_Maradona#Country), [Dunga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunga#Honours) and [Xavi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xavi#Spain).

Answer (score 9):

If [this source](http://sports.terra.com/soccer/maradona-and-other-youth-and-senior-world-champions-photos,99ffb3331afaf310VgnVCM5000009ccceb0aRCRD.html) ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20141110220044/https://sports.terra.com/soccer/maradona-and-other-youth-and-senior-world-champions-photos,99ffb3331afaf310VgnVCM5000009ccceb0aRCRD.html)) is correct, then the following list includes all players who won both U-20 World Cup and senior World Cup until 2013. There are some later additions too (based on other sources).

- [Diego Maradona](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_Maradona#Country). Maradona won the FIFA World Youth Championship in [1979](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1979_FIFA_World_Youth_Championship#Awards), and also received the Golden Ball. In [1986](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986_FIFA_World_Cup#Awards) he won the FIFA World Cup, again receiving the Golden Ball.
- [Iker Casillas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iker_Casillas#Country) won the FIFA World Youth Championship in [1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999_FIFA_World_Youth_Championship_squads#_Spain), and the FIFA World Cup in [2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup_squads#Spain), where he was voted a member of the [all-star team](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup#All-Star_Team) and also won the [Golden Glove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup_awards#Golden_Glove) award for best goalkeeper.
- [Xavi Hernandez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xavi#Spain) won the FIFA World Youth Championship in [1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999_FIFA_World_Youth_Championship_squads#_Spain). He was a member of the victorious Spanish team at [2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup_squads#Spain) World Cup, where he was also voted a member of the [all-star team](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup#All-Star_Team) of the tournament.
- [Dunga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunga#Honours) helped Brazil to win the World Youth Championship in [1983](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1983_FIFA_World_Youth_Championship_squads#_Brazil) and the World Cup in [1994](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup_squads#Brazil), where he also became a member of the [all-star team](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup#All-star_team).
- [Bebeto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bebeto#Honours) was a member of the winning Brazilian teams at the same tournaments as Dunga.
- [Jorginho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jorginho#Country) won the gold medal at the same tournaments as Dunga and Bebeto. He was in the [all-star team](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup#All-star_team) of the 1994 World Cup.
- [Cláudio Taffarel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cl%C3%A1udio_Taffarel#Country) won the World Youth Championship in [1985](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1985_FIFA_World_Youth_Championship_squads#Brazil) and the World Cup in [1994](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup_squads#Brazil).
- [Müller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCller_(footballer)#Honours) won at the same tournaments as Taffarel.
- [Dida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dida_(footballer,_born_1973)#Honours) won the World Youth Championship in [1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_FIFA_World_Youth_Championship_squads#_Brazil) and was a member of the winning Brazil team at the [2002](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup_squads#Brazil) World Cup, although he did not play a game there.
- [Carlos Marchena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlos_Marchena#Country) won the World Youth Championship in [1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999_FIFA_World_Youth_Championship_squads#_Spain) and the World Cup in [2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup_squads#Spain).
- [Lionel Messi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Messi#International_career) won the FIFA World Youth Championship in [2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2005_FIFA_World_Youth_Championship), winning both the Golden Ball and Golden Boot, then won the FIFA World Cup in [2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup), where he again won the Golden Ball.
- [Papu Gómez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papu_G%C3%B3mez) and [Ángel Di María](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81ngel_Di_Mar%C3%ADa) won U-20 World Cup in [2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_FIFA_U-20_World_Cup_squads#_Argentina) and FIFA World Cup in [2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup_squads#Argentina).
- [Alphonse Areola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphonse_Areola),
  [Paul Pogba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Pogba),
  [Florian Thauvin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florian_Thauvin) and
  [Samuel Umtiti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Umtiti)
  won U-20 World Cup in [2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_FIFA_U-20_World_Cup_squads) and FIFA World Cup in [2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup_squads#France).

---

Sources:

- [Maradona and other youth and senior world champions](http://sports.terra.com/soccer/maradona-and-other-youth-and-senior-world-champions-photos,99ffb3331afaf310VgnVCM5000009ccceb0aRCRD.html) ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20141110220044/https://sports.terra.com/soccer/maradona-and-other-youth-and-senior-world-champions-photos,99ffb3331afaf310VgnVCM5000009ccceb0aRCRD.html))
- [Coupe du monde U20 : Que vont-ils devenir?](http://www.lagrinta.fr/coupe-du-monde-u20-que-vont-ils-devenir&7245/) ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20160203030946/http://www.lagrinta.fr/coupe-du-monde-u20-que-vont-ils-devenir&7245/))
- Wikipedia articles of individual world cups